# how to make a function to return a generic of struct?

Tags: go, generics

I'm learning genric in go.
I have struct `User` and `Member`, and I want to make a function to return `User` or `Member`. How I can achieve this?

edit: I don't want to use `interface{}` or `any`

Comment: You may use `interface{}` result type, so you can return any value (also not just `User` and `Member` ). You may use 2 return values (Go allows that). Or use 2 different functions.

Comment: I don't want to use interface{} because in go 1.18 has generic. and I still learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `interface{}` result type, so you can return any value (also not just `User` and `Member`). You may use 2 return values (Go allows that). Or use 2 different functions.

If you want to do it using generics, this is how it could look like:

```
func getSomething[T User | Member]() T {
    var result T
    return result
}
```

`getSomething()` has a type parameter that allows `User` or `Member`.

This is how you could call it:

```
fmt.Printf("%T\n", getSomething[User]())
fmt.Printf("%T\n", getSomething[Member]())
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/h4lTTYOTeHR?v=gotip)):

```
main.User
main.Member
```

Comment: I see thank you @isca, I complicated because the official docs are using `interface` https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics.

Answer (score 2):

`interface{}` has always been an eyesore in Go - so Go `1.18` (with Generics support) you can now use the new keyword `any` for any type:

```
func myFunc[T any](in T) (out T) {
    // do stuff
    return
}
```

or you can use a targeted subset of types as @icza outlines `User | Member`

https://go.dev/play/p/RGm6cl4ncqA?v=gotip